# Get CAS cookie on Java

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, cas

I'm trying to authenticate my Java application with a CAS-auth-based web. What I understand so far is that I need to handle cookies. I have retrieved the cookies from the login-form HTML page, and it sends me an `JSESSION` cookie. The value of this cookie is retrieved with a POST submit.

My problem is that after that submit, I got an "Successful login" HTML as response, but I don't know how to get the CASTGT cookie. I need it to access the services on the web (Intranet, being specific).

Additionally, in the browser, after the login I see the two cookies (JSESSION and CASTGT) from the domain who provides the login form, and another JESSION cookie from the domain which provides the intranet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to deal with cookies directly at all. So long as you have declared the AuthenticationFilter and ValidationFilter instances in the web.xml file of your web application, you will be able to interact with your CAS Server instance through the CAS Java client API.

See *[Configuring the JA-SIG CAS Client for Java in the web.xml](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Configuring+the+JA-SIG+CAS+Client+for+Java+in+the+web.xml)*  for more information.

Comment: uhmm yes, I think so, the problem is that I do not own the neither website or the webapp, I'm trying to interact with it parsing the HTML code. And I could, until they changed the authentication system a week ago.
So, I need to get some cookie to identify the user and get the HTML code.